# Is it possible to insert a string from a textbox into a column?

Tags: string, ibm-doors

Is it possible that when you push an insert/ok button that it will insert the contents of a textbox into a specified column?

say i have column **TEST** and i type *"testing123"* into the text box and push insert it will fill entire **TEST** column with the text *"testing123"*?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. 
But the answer depends on what you mean by "column".
Columns show the contents of attributes or the result of an attribute DXL script or of a Layout DXL script.

If you want to set an attribute: the result of a field DB or a text DB can be retrieved with `string sContent = get (dbElement)`, an attribute X of an object o1 can be set with `o1.x = sContent`, the callback function on what to do when a button is pushed is defined when you define the button in the dialog using the perm `DBE button(DB box, string label,void callback(DBE)) [,bool variableSize|int style])`.

But judging from your question I get the feeling that you should get a lot deeper into the basics of DOORS before you will be able to program dialog boxes.

An alternative for you might be the usage of a form. http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYQBZ_9.6.1/com.ibm.doors.requirements.doc/topics/t_useformstoeditmodules.html gives an introduction to forms